# Очень медленное отображение таблицы MySQL в DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

Доброго времени суток всем!

Пытаюсь сделать прогу на C# для работы с БД на MySql.
Таблица содержит около 12 тысяч записей и я пытаюсь выгрузить ее в DataGridView следующим кодом:

Первый вариант:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM placeworks";
MySqlCommand command;
MySqlDataReader reader;                       
command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();                       

List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    data.Add(new string[10]);
    data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][5] = reader[5].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][6] = reader[6].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][7] = reader[7].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][8] = reader[8].ToString();
    data[data.Count - 1][9] = reader[9].ToString();               
}

reader.Close();
dgvFromDB.Rows.Clear();

foreach (string[] s in data)
    dgvFromDB.Rows.Add(s);
```

Второй вариант:

```
DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from placeworks", connection);            
da.Fill(dsTable);
dgvFromDB.DataSource = dsTable.Tables[0];
```

В обоих случаях мало того, что данные очень долго загружаются, еще и отрисовка DataGridView - просто белый фон, пока не получит данные.

Я пробовал сделать постраничный просмотр (при помощи limit 0, 100) - чуть быстрее, но все же не то.
К тому же мне нужно затем отфильтрованные данные (или всю таблицу) экспортировать в .xlsx, а при таком варианте он экспортирует только те 100 записей, которые загружены в DataGridView.
Прокручивать в цикле каждые 100 записей, пока не дойду до конца текущей таблицы - опять таки очень долго.

Есть ли способы сделать это все побыстрее и по-нормальному??
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обычно для таких целей показывают прогресс бар и фоне загружают не перерисовывая грид до окончания.

Comment: Ну, даже если так - количество времени для загрузки и обработки все равно не меняется. А я думал, может есть технологии или библиотеки, которые могли бы упростить и ускорить этот процесс

Comment: Понимаете сама прорисовка не занимает очень много времени во всяком случае не должна. Вы засеките время после того как получили данные и начали прорисовку. И вообще разделите на шаги и подсчитайте время каждого шага. Вы занимаетесь оптимизацией значит у вас должно быть текущие замеры.

Comment: @Skywalker Попробуйте использовать `BindingList` в качестве `DataSource` и закидывать данные в ссылку на него порционно. Возможно стоит использовать EntityFramework и его методы Skip и Take, для получения данных порциями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую решить Вашу задачу со своей позиции.

Продублируем постановку, нужно заполнять грид большим количеством записей из БД, при этом это нужно ASAP, чтобы не заставлять клиента ждать полной загрузки.

Для доступа к базе будем использовать EntityFramework. Инструмент прекрасно подходит для очень многих вещей. Напишем класс модели и подключим его к БД.

Обозначим, что `DataSource` в гриде будет использовать `BindingList<T>`

Напишем запрос с порционной выборкой из базы данных.
Будем делать это асинхронно, чтобы не вызывать блокировку формы во время работы EntityFramework, поэтому создадим таску, которая будет работать сама по себе и передадим в нее ссылку на наш BindingList. Важно! Обязательно оборачиваем код внутри таски в `try{...}catch()`, чтобы быть уверенным, что таска не умрет без ответа, а вернет причину отказа.

Будем работать при помощи Skip() и Take(). Нужно создать цикл, который будет запрашивать данные из EntityFramework по N записей за раз. Важное уточнение, для увеличения производительности, в параметры методов Skip и Take нужно передавать ссылки на поля, а не константные значения.

```
int pickCount;
int skipCount; 
var querry = context.Set<T>().Skip(()=> skipCount).Take(() => pickCount);
```

Код выше создает запрос, который мы будем использовать внутри цикла, модифицируя skipCount, и вызывая выполнение запроса при помощи `querry.ToList();` Запомнтие главное, не запускайте выполнение нескольких запросов на одном контексте.

Каждый раз получая порцию данных нам необходимо класть ее в наш `BindingList<T>`. Обязательно используем оператор `lock(_bindingList){///}`, чтобы обеспечить потокобезопасность.

Надеюсь, мне удалось помочь с Вашим вопросом.